To which arithmetic\set theory this theory is bi-interpretable?
$\textbf{Logic:}$ Mono-sorted first order logic with equality.
$\textbf{Extralogical Primitives: }  <, \in$
$ \textbf{Axioms:}$

$ \textbf{Order:} \  x < y  < z \to x < z $

$ \textbf{Finiteness:}  \\  y \in x \to   \exists \, l,u \in x \forall m \in x :  m \neq l \leftrightarrow l < m  \leq u    $

$\textbf{Sets: }  \forall n \exists! x \forall m (m \in x \leftrightarrow n \not < m \land \phi)$, if $x$ is not free in formula $\phi$.


This theory is just a reformulation of the theory presented in posting titled "Is this theory synonymous with PA?", and as shown per answers, it is not bi-interpretable with $\sf PA$, though it is mutually interpretable with it.
Two questions:

To which theory in the language of $\sf PA$ this theory is bi-interpretable?


To which fragment of the standard set theory this theory is bi-interpretable?


Your theory is true in the one-element universe $\{a\}$ in which $a<a$ is true and $a\in a$ is false. The order transitivity holds trivially in this case; the finiteness axiom holds vacuously; and the sets axiom holds, since the LHS and RHS of the biconditional are both false, and there is a unique $x$, since $x=a$ is the only object available.
So it seems that this theory does not necessarily express any interesting version of set theory.
